# How can I fix this login error in MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb

I recently install MariaDB and use DB

but it has error on login

I check my plugin

`root localhost mysql_native_password`

```
 Enter password: 
 ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

How can I fix??

Comment: When you installed MariaDB, did you setup the root password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent versions of MariaDB will authenticate users via [unix_socket plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/) when connecting via unix_socket (localhost).

So if you need to connect as root, just do a

```
$ sudo mysql
```

and enter password afterwards.